# SwiftUI MacOS Form Custom Layout

Tags: macos, layout, swiftui

I had an earlier question that I got awesome help to but there's something not quite right with the layout still. Figured I'd create a new question rather than continue that one.

I'm making a custom picker using a button and want it laid out like the other pickers, textfields, etc on my form. In the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70962859/customize-the-swiftui-form-label-layout-for-macos?noredirect=1#comment125467082_70962859) I learned to use the alignmentGuide. However that isn't working as the field isn't quite lined up with the others AND I can only make the window a bit smaller and then it locks into place. I want it to line up with above and be dynamic to window size adjustments when running.

Here's what it looks like right now
[image]

This is as small as I can make it:
[image]

And here's the current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var myName:String = "Kyra"
@State var selectedPickerItem: String?
var pickerItems = ["item 1",
                   "item 2",
                   "item 3",
                   "item 4",
                   "item 5",
                   "item 6"]
@State var showingPopover:Bool = false
@State var selectedItems = [String]()
@State var allItems:[String] = ["more items",
                     "another item",
                     "and more",
                     "still more",
                     "yet still more",
                     "and the final item"]
@State private var commonSize = CGSize()
@State private var commonTextSize = CGSize()

var body: some View {
    Form {
        
        TextField("My Name:", text: $myName, prompt: Text("What's your name?"))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color(red: 0.4192, green: 0.2358, blue: 0.3450))
        
        Picker(selection: $selectedPickerItem, label: Text("Pick Something:")) {
            Text("No Chosen Item").tag(nil as String?)
            ForEach(pickerItems, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item).tag(item as String?)
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color(red: 0.2645, green: 0.3347, blue: 0.4008))
        
        
        HStack() {
            Text("Select Items:")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .readSize { textSize in
                    commonTextSize = textSize
                }
            Button(action: {
                showingPopover.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "\($selectedItems.count).circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .font(.title2)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
            .readSize { textSize in
                commonSize = textSize
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in (d.width - commonSize.width) })
        .background(Color(red: 0.4192, green: 0.2358, blue: 0.3450))
    }
    .padding()
}
}

// FROM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577462/get-width-of-a-view-using-in-swiftui
extension View {
  func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
background(
  GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
    Color.clear
      .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
  }
)
.onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
  }
}

private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

Comment: I was looking into this for your last question, and it gets tricky ... I didn't find a way to get the width of the other input elements (without label) in a flexible layout.  Can't you just define a fixed width for all of them? (Pickers and Buttons becoming too wide looks funny anyway :)

Comment: That might end up being what I do. I just wasn't sure if the user would want to make the window smaller or larger. Thank you. I'll leave this up just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since upgraded to Ventura 13.0 beta on my Mac and upgraded Xcode too. With the upgrade I still have this issue; however, the SwiftUI upgrade includes the `Grid` control which fixes this layout bug. I figured with this current upgrade `Grid` I'd answer this question and mark as solved.

With the upgrade the controls still didn't line up, although I was able to make it as small as I wanted.

Form controls are still not lined up:
[image: Form controls are still not lined up.]

But I can make the form as small as I want however the controls' start and end locations jump around as I do.
[image: But I can make the form as small as I want however the controls' start and end locations jump around as I do.]

With the update I was able to use the new `Grid` control ([documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid)) to layout my controls making them look so much better.

[image: Screenshot of the apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid]

Here it is using Grid. I can drag the edges of the window to make it as small or large as I want without any weirdness.
[image: The new layout using Grid. Can make as small and large as I want.]

To do this I replaced my `VStack` with `Grid` and enclosed each control section with `GridRow`. My two bottom controls were too skinny so I combined the grid cells together so they'd take up the whole space by using the modifier `.gridCellColumns(3)`. Code is:

```
    Grid {
        GridRow {
            TextField("My Name:", text: $myName, prompt: Text("What's your name?"))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color(red: 0.4192, green: 0.2358, blue: 0.3450))
        }
        .gridCellColumns(3)
        
        GridRow {
            Picker(selection: $selectedPickerItem, label: Text("Pick Something:")) {
                Text("No Chosen Item").tag(nil as String?)
                ForEach(pickerItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item).tag(item as String?)
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color(red: 0.2645, green: 0.3347, blue: 0.4008))
        }
        .gridCellColumns(3)
        
        GridRow {
            HStack() {
                // Rather than a picker we're using Text for the label and a button for the picker itself
                Text("Select Items:")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Button(action: {
                    // The only job of the button is to toggle the showing popover boolean so it pops up and we can select our items
                    showingPopover.toggle()
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "\($selectedItems.count).circle")
                            .font(.title2)
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                            .font(.caption)
                    }
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                    MultiSelectPickerView(allItems: allItems, selectedItems: $selectedItems)
                    // If you have issues with it being too skinny you can hardcode the width
                        .frame(width: 300)
                }
            }
            .background(Color(red: 0.4192, green: 0.2358, blue: 0.3450))
        }
        .gridCellColumns(3)
    }
    .padding()
    
    
    // Made a quick text section so we can see what we selected
    Section("My selected items are:", content: {
        Text(selectedItems.joined(separator: "\n"))
    })
```

Hope this helps you out if you come across a similar issue.