# SwiftUI form alignment macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to include a custom `HStack` row in a SwiftUI `Form` as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("Text", text: .constant("test"))
        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: .constant(true))
            .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle())
        HStack {
            Text("Label")
            MenuButton("Menu") {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Clicked Pizza")
                }) { Text("Pizza") }
                Button(action: {
                    print("Clicked Pasta")
                }) { Text("Pasta") }
            }
            TextField("Topping", text: .constant("Cheese"))
                .labelsHidden()
        }
        
    }
    .padding()
}
```

resulting in

[image: SwiftUI form output with wrong alignment]

However, I would like `Label` to be vertically aligned with `Toggle` and `Menu` vertically aligned with the toggle.

Is there a standard way of choosing the alignment mode for the custom `HStack` row?

Comment: Interesting link about the final solution (LabeledContent)⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2022/2210052/#advanced-controls 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### macOS 13 only

The new [`LabeledContent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labeledcontent#) view in SwiftUI will help you:

```swift
LabeledContent("Label") {
  MenuButton("Menu") {
    Button(action: {
      print("Clicked Pizza")
    }) { Text("Pizza") }
    Button(action: {
      print("Clicked Pasta")
    }) { Text("Pasta") }
  }
  TextField("Topping", text: .constant("Cheese"))
    .labelsHidden()
  }
}
```

[image: An example layout with LabeledContent in SwiftUI for macOS 13]

However, this view has not been backported to earlier versions of macOS, so if you need to support earlier versions you'll need another approach.

---

## Earlier versions of macOS

Building on the preference key code from @Nhat Nguyen Duc, the key is to use alignment guides rather than padding. Creating a custom view, and with a customised preference that only measures the width:

```
struct LabeledHStack<Content: View>: View {
    var label: String
    var content: () -> Content
    @State var labelWidth: CGFloat = 0

    init(_ label: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(label)
                .readSize { self.labelWidth = $0 }
            content()
        }
        .alignmentGuide(.leading) { _ in labelWidth + 10 } // see note
    }
}

struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) { }
}

extension View {
    func readWidth(onChange: @escaping (CGFloat) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size.width)
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
}
```

Note that in the custom view I've added 10 pixels to quickly emulate the spacing between a label and its form elements. There is probably a better way to make this work for accessibility sizes, etc., (e.g., the use of a `@ScaledMetric` value). You might also wish to apply this as padding rather than in the alignment guide calculation.

Below has a line with macOS13's `LabeledContent`, followed by `LabeledHStack`:

[image: A form with LabeledHStack]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the way to do it. Annoyingly I don't want to target macOS 13 exclusively

Comment: @Julian I've updated with a solution for older macOS versions, based on Nhat Nguyen Duc's preferences-based approach but using a custom alignment guide and wrapped into a custom view.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your content inside a **VStack** and use its `alignment` modifier to align all the content to the leading e.g:

> **VStack(alignment: .leading)**

like this:

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            TextField("Text", text: .constant("test"))
            Toggle("Toggle", isOn: .constant(true))
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle())
            HStack {
                Text("Label")
                MenuButton("Menu") {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Clicked Pizza")
                    }) { Text("Pizza") }
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Clicked Pasta")
                    }) { Text("Pasta") }
                }
                TextField("Topping", text: .constant("Cheese"))
                    .labelsHidden()
            }
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity)
        }
        
    }
    .padding()
}
```

See working example here:
[image: See working example here]

Comment: Thanks but this only aligns the labels and not the rest, correct?

Answer (score 2):

## macOS 13

```swift
LabeledContent {
    HStack { 
        // ...
    }
} label: {
    Text("Count")
}
```

- Read more about `LabeledContent` [here](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/07/13/mastering-labeledcontent-in-swiftui/)

---

## Previous version

> Idea: Calculate the size of the label using GeometryReader, and offset the view by its width.

```swift
@State private var textSize = CGSize.zero

var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("Text", text: .constant("test"))
            .padding(.leading, -textSize.width)
        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: .constant(true))
            .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle())
            .padding(.leading, -textSize.width)
        HStack {
            Text("Label")
                .readSize { textSize in
                    self.textSize = textSize
                }
            MenuButton("Menu") {
                Button("Pizza") {
                    print("Clicked Pizza")
                }
                Button("Pasta") {
                    print("Clicked Pasta")
                }
            }
            TextField("Topping", text: .constant("Cheese"))
                .labelsHidden()
        }
        .padding(.leading, -textSize.width - 10)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .padding(.leading, textSize.width + 10)
    .padding()
}
```

- `extension View`

```swift
extension View {
    func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
}
```

- `struct SizePreferenceKey`

```swift
struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) { }
}
```

- **Bonus:** For a button that contains only label, you can use

```swift
Button(<#String#>) { <#Action#> }
```

instead of

```swift
Button(action: { <#Action#> }) { Text(<#String#>) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make the pre macOS 13 work if `Label` is the longest of the labels?

Comment: Adding padding to others will fix it. I have edited the answer